# Facebook JS SDK check specific like of logged in user

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can't seem to check if a logged in user likes a specific Facebook Business page(URL).  This keeps coming back as undefined.  Notice anything wrong here?

```
function postLike() {
    FB.api(
       'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes',
       'get',
       { id: objectToLike,
         privacy: {'value': 'SELF'} },
       function(response) {
         if (!response) {
           alert('Error occurred.');
         } else if (response.error) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
             'Error: ' + response.error.message;
         } else {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
             'Business page is ' +
             response.object + '</a>';
         }
       }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did make the call using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fog.likes) to study the JSON structure? 
`response.object` should be `response.data[0].data.object` and since it's object! you have to use `response.data[0].data.object.toSource()`

Comment: Adam, nice catch... bottom one did the trick, thanks.  Would you mind explaining what the .toSource() does/comes from?

Comment: I spoke too soon, that didn't return like I thought.  All that I am trying to get is the current logged in user to check if they already like a certain FB Page or not, and return basically a yes/no.  Am I on the right track, I know very little about Facebook SDK.

Comment: _"if they already like a certain FB Page or not"_ You shouldn't use the call `/og.likes` because it's non-facebook pages it's used for `Open graph objects` (URLs) You should use `me/likes` and then check if your page id exists in response